# zeppeline broken pipe error

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, apache-zeppelin

i use a zeppelin with a report for other team members.
people always say to me.. "zeppelin is not working, fixed it"

zeppelin error is it.

> java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed) class
>   java.sql.SQLException
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.runAsyncOnServer(HiveStatement.java:317)
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:250)
>   org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.executeSql(JDBCInterpreter.java:322)
>   org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.interpret(JDBCInterpreter.java:408)
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:94)
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:341)
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:176)
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

i think the issue that is a hive, zeppelin connection error , is right?
how i can fix it?

Comment: What version of Zeppelin are you using? Also, by chance, do you have Spark installed on the machines?